# Is there any ready to use crawler or tool to extract links from website

Tags: search, web-crawler

There is one blog on website and there are many pdf links on there. But i don't want to go through all the pages.

is there any tool /script i can use so that i can extract all the link like

```
http://www.abc.com/code=1221212
```

so that then I can use IDM to get those links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below links might be helpful for you.

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

[WatiN](http://watin.org/)